# Validating radio buttons in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with validating the radio buttons in Laravel.

In My form there is a radio-set for sex. 
`male` and `female`

Now, I don't know how should I validate them using laravel's built-in validation rules.

Answer (score 6):

Go and use `in` rule [[link]](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-in).
Define rule like this

```
$rules = [
    'sex'   => 'required|in:male,female',
];
```

But since there are only two options (male and female) and radio button does not let you pick any other, after form submission, there would be only these situations:
1, nothing selected - no value
2, something selected - eighter male, or female.

So this would be sufficient after all

```
$rules = [
    'sex'   => 'required',
];
```

## Edit

In the end, I would go for `required|in:male,female` rule to prevent some clever heads from injecting custom values. Bulletproof ;)

Comment: If the user is _required_ to select one option then put a `checked` HTML attribute on one of them and use the `required` rule. That way there should be no case where this rule fails, except when the user messes with the markup client-side (firebug, dev console, fiddler, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, but preselecting "male" or "female" may be weird for user. Len them do that :) If they don't show them error message.

Comment: It's common practice (in IT at least) to set the default to "female", just to be extra safe :)

Comment: Why so? Is there any story/reason for this? :) Sounds interesting.

Comment: People consider this a trend, feminism, courtesy or a lot of other things. I know the article is not strictly related to this but the principle is the same. Though _not_ assuming a certain sex seems more polite IMHO. If *required* to pick one I'd go with "she" or "female" though. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun?rq=1

Comment: Ohm girls... Could expect this kind of answer. Simply they would go mad if the see "male" preselected. Fortunately, men don't care. Thanks for article, going to take a look.

Comment: Bit late to the party but upvoted Andreyco's comment because you should never trust your users. Like sergui said; there is a possibility of dom manipulation. So you need to validate everything server side anyway. Not pre-selecting keeps both sexes equal and not setting an default value means that lazy users (users that just don't care which sex they have according to your system) are forced to choose; if you have to click something the chance that you pick your true sex is more likely. So, in my opinion, not preselecting anything, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is enough to validate,Enter command in CMD php artisan make:request sex,and open the request and write the code like  shows

```
    public function rules()
{

       return[
            'sex' => 'required',
        ];

}
```